How to display a counter after open new website with window.open() or any other method
If I click on a button it will open a new browser tab and run a website. I want to set up a counter so that user can see how many times he spend.Counter should display only after open new website with button I had clicked.
function openTask(url, taskId) {
    const newTab = window.open(url + "?task=" + taskId, "_blank");

    const startTime = Date.now();
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        const elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;

        if (newTab && !newTab.closed && newTab.document.body) {
            const timerElement = newTab.document.createElement("div");
            timerElement.innerHTML =
                "<h1 style='position: fixed; top: 10px; right: 10px; background-color: white; z-index: 9999;'>Time Spent: " +
                Math.floor(elapsedTime / 1000) +
                " seconds</h1>";
            newTab.document.body.appendChild(timerElement);
        }

        if (elapsedTime >= 30000) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            if (!newTab.closed) {
                newTab.close();
            }

            window.location.href = "https://mywebsite.com";
        }
    }, 1000);
} 

